# Django OneToOne field in admin

Tags: python, django

Here is a model in Django:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User)
    moredata = models.CharField('More data', max_length=255)
```

I want to put all the user fields in that model's edit/create page in the Django admin. So I did this:

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```

But Django says that there are no foreign keys to Member on User, which is completely true. Is there a way to fix this?

If I don't use the admin class, all I get is a list of users to pick from.

Ideally, I'd like the `User` type to be invisible to administrators and have them only create and edit derived User types.

Instead of a OneToOne relation, should I be extending the actual `User` type instead?

Comment: There's only one so why would you use inlines (instead of a select box)? How does that make it "invisible"?

Comment: The point is to make two types of users, with different properties.

Comment: I get the general design, what I'm trying to understand is how you expected the inlines to behave with a OneToOne field

Comment: I would like the fields of the "User" model to be present and editable in the derived model's edit page.

Comment: So why `editable=False`? And what's wrong with the default widget?

Comment: I thought I'd removed that, sorry. Let me fix that... But, anyway, I don't want a list of users in the derived type, a want actual user detail fields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39977/discussion-between-eje211-and-yuvi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the chat, the built-in User object is meant to be used in the admin site. But in your case, it is irrelevent to your models, and only adds limitations and complications.

In that case, the best approach would be to use your own models as independent user classes and use the built-in User for the admin (or not at all). To do that you need to subclass the AbstractBaseUser and follow the instructions here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

It's really very detailed, and if you face any trouble with it, come back here to SO someone will surely help with that